# Centering a video in the middle of the page while having a side menu on the left. html/css

Tags: html, css, center

I'm creating a site but one thing doesnt seem to work. I want to center this video while having a side menu. The video is somewhat in the middle but not exactly. Very frustating.

```
 <html>
<head>
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
        <a href=""> <h1>title</h1> </a>


        <ul>  <li><a href="default.asp">Tour</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">about</a></li>
</ul>






        <iframe src="youtubevideourl" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <p>
            <h2> lorem ipsim nog wat </h2>
        </p>
        <p>
            <h2> jaja </h2>
        </p>













        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px;">
            <footer>

                <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:@gmail.com">
                @gmail.com</a>.</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

</body>
```

with this css code

```
   img {
display: block;

width: 20%;
}

body {
background-image: url("anbuachter.png");
}

h1{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    font-size: 100px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url("oldlondon.ttf");
}

iframe {
    width: 560px;
    height: 350px;
    display: block;

    margin: 0 auto;

}

h2{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Courier New";
}

footer{ font-family:"Palatino Linotype";
    font-size: 15px;

   }

div.jiri{
text-align:center;
font-family: myFirstFont;
font-size:30px;
padding-top: 50px;
}

a { 
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

div.menu {
font-family: myFirstFont;
font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: myFirstFont;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
}

li a 
display: block;
text-align:left;
margin: 15px;
}
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe {
    width: 560px;
    height: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 400px;
```

Let me know if this does what you needed.